# Why does my Deutsche Bahn ticket have a different number and time?

Tags: tickets, public-transport, train-stations

I have looked at my ICE DB ticket and the train number and time is different to the one available on the website for seat reservations. Is this because they didn’t run that train? The destination is still the same (Köln to Berlin) just a different arrival time. Now I am scared I reserved the wrong seat on the wrong train. I did book the Flexipreis Europa. Can someone also explain what it means?

Comment: I'm afraid it is difficult to have an answer without knowing at minimum the date, time and route of the train you (think you) are taking or have booked.

Comment: And ideally, the number and schedule of both the rain you booked and the one you now found.

Comment: DST got into effect on Sunday, maybe the site got confused

Comment: What are the dates and times of departure and arrival for the train you intended?  What are the dates and times of departure and arrival for the train on your ticket?

Comment: On the 02/08/2023 was supposed to leave at 14:48 from Köln and arrive at berlin at 19:15.

Comment: Please give us the train numbers (ICE1234). It's bit strange, because there is a 13:48 and a 15:48 departure, but the trains at even hours run on a different route and take longer. If possible, could you copy the cryptic text in the "Über:" field as well.

Comment: August second is a very long time in the future. The railways do not really expect people to book that far in advance, and thus you can get in to all kinds of weird issues, like train schedules changing by the time you travel...

Comment: Also, for a connection from Köln to Berlin Flexipreis Europa doesn't make sense, that's only offered on international connections.

Answer (score 3):

A "flex preis" ticket is a flexible ticket, valid on any train that runs the route you bought the ticket for. So you can take any Köln to Berlin service on the days your ticket is valid (see the top of the ticket).

Your reservation will be for a specific train, but you are not limited to taking that train. Just when you take another train you will not have a guaranteed seat. Your reservation should have the train number, the car number and the seat number on it.

Given that you have a flexible ticket you do not run the risk of being on the wrong train, as long as you are on the right train route.